# Using QGIS calculate distance of point along a line

Tags: qgis, network

I have lots of points, and a road (lines) and I would like to calculate from point A to point B (the distance must route through the roads (lines).

I found this [QGIS calculate distance of point along a line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25337/qgis-calculate-distance-of-point-along-a-line) , but when I'm trying to do a v.distance, I don't see it saving the distance into the DB.

I need the DB to show:

```
Source      Destination       Distance 
Point A     Point B          10.0011 
Point A     Point C           101.12 
point A     Point D            1212  
Point B     point c           121.0 
point B     Point D         31.0 
...         ...                ...
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should try Network-Analysis tool (it is in core now). [Here is its description in the QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html). Here is a python-scripting [tutorial](http://gis-lab.info/qa/qgis-network-analysis-lib.html) for network-analysis (it is in Russian, but google-translate should help).

Comment: When I ran the 2nd command from that page : "Director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector ( MYS_roads , - 1 ,  '' ,  '' ,  '' ,  3  )" , it gave me an error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'MYS_roads' is not defined. " Where can I get help for this? :)

Comment: @user10405, obviously you haven't defined 'MYS_roads' variable. General help (including help from the author of this tool) you can get at [this thread](http://gis-lab.info/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9648). You can freely ask your questions in English there.