# How to order points along a line?

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, order

I have a bus line with bus stops along the route.
[image]

The sample data looks like this:

```
LINESTRING (-70.57243474999999933 -33.37452829000000065, -70.57308152999999606 -33.37470645999999874, -70.57543062999999961 -33.37539473999999728, -70.57551596999999788 -33.3754228700000013, -70.57676012999999671 -33.37580358000000302, -70.57838608999999508 -33.37581671000000227, -70.5790643100000068 -33.37582045999999991, -70.58024559999999781 -33.37582420999999755, -70.58068577000000232 -33.37587485000000243, -70.5810989999999947 -33.37592361000000096, -70.58192544999999996 -33.3760173800000004, -70.58280580000000271 -33.37611865000000222)

POINT(-70.58176091969386334 -33.37599871220383818)
POINT(-70.58081166577235877 -33.37588970535671251)
POINT(-70.5789007062584659 -33.37581955540557743)
POINT(-70.57517086297514197 -33.3753186292262285)
POINT(-70.57426670966613358 -33.37505371514445329)
```

How can I order (add an order ID) the bus stops along the route?

Any Open Source Software is welcome. Preferably something that can be automated (QGIS, Python, PostGIS).

Comment: Which software?

Comment: Related: [QGIS calculate distance of point along a line](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25337/qgis-calculate-distance-of-point-along-a-line)

Comment: @dassouki I updated my question and added software. However I also appreciate general ideas/algorithms on how to solve it that are software independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using PostGIS, you can order the bus stops according to their value returned for an [`ST_Line_Locate_point()`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Line_Locate_Point.html) call.

---

This is how it looks if I apply it to the linestring and points you supplied:

```
SELECT  
  ST_Line_Locate_Point(line.f1, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-70.58176091969386334 -33.37599871220383818)')) as A,
  ST_Line_Locate_Point(line.f1, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-70.58081166577235877 -33.37588970535671251)')) as B,
  ST_Line_Locate_Point(line.f1, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-70.5789007062584659 -33.37581955540557743)')) as C,
  ST_Line_Locate_Point(line.f1, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-70.57517086297514197 -33.3753186292262285)')) as D,
  ST_Line_Locate_Point(line.f1, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-70.57426670966613358 -33.37505371514445329)')) as E
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (-70.57243474999999933 -33.37452829000000065, -70.57308152999999606 -33.37470645999999874, -70.57543062999999961 -33.37539473999999728, -70.57551596999999788 -33.3754228700000013, -70.57676012999999671 -33.37580358000000302, -70.57838608999999508 -33.37581671000000227, -70.5790643100000068 -33.37582045999999991, -70.58024559999999781 -33.37582420999999755, -70.58068577000000232 -33.37587485000000243, -70.5810989999999947 -33.37592361000000096, -70.58192544999999996 -33.3760173800000004, -70.58280580000000271 -33.37611865000000222)') 
        as f1
  ) as line;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   A              | B               | C               | D               | E
0.900519204659061;0.810142121650764;0.629032670938557;0.269386835869428;0.180270638952756
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

And a pic, just in case that helps..

[image]