# Measuring distance between points along line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, distance, road, measurements

I have a road network and different points connected to the roads. I would like to measure the distance between several points along the roads.

Basically I want to do the same like the Road Graph Plugin, but I want to measure not only the distance between two points and also would like to get the results in an attribute table.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [QGIS calculate distance of point along a line](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25337/qgis-calculate-distance-of-point-along-a-line).

Answer (score 5):

I first thought this question was basically same as another recent question [Points layer distance from the start of line layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280112/points-layer-distance-from-the-start-of-line-layer-in-qgis).

However, there is an added complexity in this one, that OP requires **distance between** (not a distance from the start point).

So I needed **QGIS 3.0** `get_feature_by_id()` function to calculate the difference between records.

(1) Calculate the distance of each point along the line, from the start point of the line.

Please see [Points layer distance from the start of line layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280112/points-layer-distance-from-the-start-of-line-layer-in-qgis)

(2) Calculate distance between points, based on the `distance` taken from previous step (1).

Again, open the attribute table of `Points` layer, which has `distance` field.

Create a new field `interval` by the below expression:

```
  attribute(get_feature_by_id('Points', $id+1), 'distance')
  - attribute(get_feature_by_id('Points', $id), 'distance')
```

This expression calculates the difference between points by (`value at next row` minus `value at current row`).

NB: The `$id` is unrelated to `id` field shown in the picture. Sorry if it is confusing.

[image]