# Points layer distance from the start of line layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I tried to find out and read multiple similar questions but not able to get answer to my question. 
I have two layers; points (various location data) and lines (roads). My aim is to calculate all points distance from the start of the road layer and populate this in points layer attribute (snapshot attached). Points are little away from the road line. I checked LRS but I did not find there. I am using QGIS 2.18.

[image: Points distance from start]

[image: points distance of multiple roads]

Comment: Where is the "start of the road layer"? Is the road layer just one road, and the start is the first vertex on it?

Comment: Star of road layer is direction and first vertex. I have multiple roads with unique code field and similarly multiple points along these roads.

Comment: So you want the *straight line distance* from points with some code=i to the first vertex (which for your example might be the bottom left point of the line) of the road with code=i ? All roads are a simple single linestring (not complex features with branches)?

Comment: first of all thanks for the very helpful manual. I would like to take up the topic again to determine the m-value. Is it possible to calculate the corresponding m-values of the points using a routed and calibrated line? The expression "m($geometry)" can be used to determine the m-values. Unfortunately, I couldn't include this in the calculation. Further information can be found at: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224665/qgis-extract-nodes-with-m-values-for-linear-referencing Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi. Answers are ment to be answers not questions. Please post it as a new question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155735)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155735)

Answer (score 13):

QGIS 2.18 has a new function `line_locate_point()`.

Open the Field Calculator and try this expression:

```
line_locate_point( geometry:=geometry(get_feature('Line', 'id', '1')), point:=$geometry)
```

(I assumed the `id` field of your first line is `1`).

[image]

It will return the distance along the line, something like below.

[image]

---

**Update**

I noticed ongoing discussion about what distance is required for this question (i.e. *straight* or *along the line*). So I thought I would post this picture may add some clarity what this `line_locate_point()` tool gives us.

[image]

---

**Update2**

To work on multiple roads, you would better to have a field (`road_id`) in your point layer, to identify corresponding road.
Then the expression becomes:

```
line_locate_point(geometry:=geometry(get_feature('Line','id',"road_id")),point:=$geometry)
```

[image]

---

**Update3**

According to your data, please try:

```
line_locate_point(geometry:=geometry(get_feature('Line','road_id',"road_id")),point:=$geometry)
```

- Note the change (`'id'` to `'road_id'`) of the second input parameter for `get_feature()` function.
- I noticed your attribute table of line data (`road_line`) has its own `road_id` field. (It was not in my test sample. Sorry for the confusion caused.)

Comment: It is working fine Spacedman and thanks a lot for your support. Kazuhito appreciate your further clarification. Sure I want to get distance along the line not straight.

Comment: As I have hundreds of roads with codes and also thousands of points. How can I apply the code so that multiple roads and point distance can be calculated? Can we calculate 3D distance as I have elevation of each point as well? Much appreciate your support.

Comment: @Mohsin thanks for your feedback. I understand your situation. I have no knowledge how you store your data, but updated the expression as much as I can. Hope this helps.

Comment: Currently it is in shapefile and I am going to import in Postgres/PostGIS. How can we apply to multiple roads? I greatly appreciate your support.

Comment: Hi Kazuhitu, thanks for your code. I tested the code and it is not calculating distance for multiple roads. Road_id  field is text (please see attached snapshot and code). I am using following code: line_locate_point(geometry:=geometry(get_feature('road_line','id',"road_id")),point:=$geometry)

Comment: Hi @Mohsin Just to check; do you have both `id` and `road_id` fields in your point layer? (sequential `id` represents individual point, and `road_id` is indicator for the road respectively).

Comment: Yes I have a id field in points as well as in road line layer. I do not find any attachment option of snapshot while adding this comment.

Comment: @Mohsin Adding the snapshots to your original post would be helpful (there is an `edit` underneath). Such details would also help reopening the question, then others can give you more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. I added snapshot in original post showing points and road line attributes.

Comment: Thanks @Mohsin for the images of attribute tables. Please see revised syntax in **Update3**.

Comment: Dear Kazuhito, great and very valuable support from you and really appreciate. I have some issue to assign values in POINTZM and LINEZM geometry from attributes. Can I ask here or I need to ask new question? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Mohsin I think it will be worth posting a new question.