# QGIS distance between points - line_locate_point()

Tags: qgis, point, line

I need to calculate distances between points that are overlapping a layer with a line (representative of a river corridor (thus there are two layers; one is the points the other is a line). I've tried to follow this example ([Points layer distance from the start of line layer in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280112/points-layer-distance-from-the-start-of-line-layer-in-qgis?newreg=96245416a4044bcbbcd45a92c8476643)). I get an output, and I think I'm doing everything correctly, but I'm not sure what unit the distance measurement is coming out in. If I use the measuring tool in QGIS I get very different values.

See below:

[image: output]

Here are some screen shots of the attribute table, points and line layer.

However, for example, if I measure the distance between point 5 and 6 using the measuring tool I get a very different answer.

[image]

Where am I going wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the big bright yellow warning line, I would guess that the distances are expressed in degrees.

To get distances in meters, you must first reproject the lines/points to a suitable projection such as 27700

Comment: Thank you. I think this was it. I still had a problem but is seems to have fixed itself now. when I had both in the same coordinate system the line and the points wouldn't match up, and only did when they were in different systems. But I recreated the layers and eventually they matched on same CRS. Not sure why.